# Rails: Ajax calls not working with 'require jquery'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I have an AJAX call on my rails app that is not working when I include jquery in the application.js file. Whenever I submit a form (with form_for), nothing happens.  Problem is without that jquery line, I cannot get to work my html-delete-methods, resulting in another exception.

I'm working with Rails 3.2.3 and ruby 1.9.3p194

Here it goes some code:

**application.js:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

**form.html.erb:**

```
<%= form_for(user.relationships.build(id: @user.id), remote: true) do |f| %>
```

**controller.rb**

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @patient }
      format.js
end
```

What is it that's missing me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<% relationship = user.relationships.build user_id: @user.id
<%= form_for relationship, url: relationship_path(relationship, format: :js) do |f| %>
```

Comment: well, there are no errors now, but no ajax call is being made.  Just a regular http post/delete method...
thanks for your help, though!

Comment: Sorry, you need to add `remote: true` before the url parameter.

Comment: nop, still no good! I now found that I am getting an "Error (Called id for nil" for a @user variable, set in the controller.... why is that variable lost along the way??

Comment: It must not be set. Is it supposed to be @patient?